# Empty nested tuples error

Tags: c++, c++11, nested, tuples

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
int main(){

auto bt=std::make_tuple(std::tuple<>(),std::tuple<std::tuple<>>()); //Line 1
auto bt2=std::make_tuple(std::tuple<>(),std::tuple<>());             //Line 2
}
```

Why does Line 1 gives a compile error while Line 2 compiles fine? (tested in both Gcc&Clang)

Is there a possible workaround?

error message for clang

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/tuple:150:50: error: ambiguous conversion from derived class 'std::_Tuple_impl<0, std::tuple<>,
      std::tuple<std::tuple<> > >' to base class 'std::_Head_base<0, std::tuple<>, true>':
    struct std::_Tuple_impl<0, class std::tuple<>, class std::tuple<class std::tuple<> > > -> _Tuple_impl<0UL + 1, class std::tuple<class std::tuple<> > > -> _Head_base<1UL, class std::tuple<class std::tuple<> >, std::is_empty<class tuple<class tuple<> > >::value> -> class std::tuple<class std::tuple<> > -> _Tuple_impl<0, class std::tuple<> > -> _Head_base<0UL, class std::tuple<>, std::is_empty<class tuple<> >::value>
    struct std::_Tuple_impl<0, class std::tuple<>, class std::tuple<class std::tuple<> > > -> _Head_base<0UL, class std::tuple<>, std::is_empty<class tuple<> >::value>
      _Head&            _M_head()       { return _Base::_M_head(); }
                                                 ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/4.6/tuple:173:33: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::_Tuple_impl<0, std::tuple<>,
      std::tuple<std::tuple<> > >::_M_head' requested here
        _Base(std::forward<_Head>(__in._M_head())) { }
                                       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.6/tuple:334:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::_Tuple_impl<0, std::tuple<>,
      std::tuple<std::tuple<> > >::_Tuple_impl' requested here
      : _Inherited(static_cast<_Inherited&&>(__in)) { }
        ^
gcc_bug.cpp:5:10: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::tuple<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<std::tuple<> > >::tuple' requested here
        auto bt=std::make_tuple(std::tuple<>(),std::tuple<std::tuple<>>());
                ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Could it be a bug in Gcc or Clang ? Your code compiles with Visual Studio 2010. By the way, you are declaring bt twice, is that intended ?

Comment: Also, could you indicate the compile error message ?

Comment: sorry, the buggy Line 1 was commented out. I forgot to change the name, edited now.

Comment: more likely a bug in libstdc++. try with libc++ if you can.

Comment: What is the text of the compile error?

Comment: Compiles in MSVC10.  **Please post the compiler error.**  Too long for what?

Comment: gcc 4.6.2 says `internal compiler error: in build_base_path, at cp/class.c:270|`

Comment: @ecatmur: Not exactly. The code in your link compiles fine in gcc 4.7 with libstdc++ but OP's code does not.

Comment: @ecatmur I doubt it, std::tuple<std::tuple<std::tuple<>>> tp(std::tuple<std::tuple<>>()) gives error too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you found a bug in libstdc++! (This code works in clang with libc++). A reduced test case:

```
#include <tuple>

int main(){
    auto b = std::tuple<std::tuple<std::tuple<>>>{};
}
```

---

The problem is due to how `std::tuple` is implemented in libstdc++. The tuple implementation uses "recursion" with multiple-inheritance. You can think of `tuple<X, Y, Z>` as inheriting from both `X` and `tuple<Y, Z>`. This means `tuple<tuple<>>` will inherit from both `tuple<>` and `tuple<>` and that will cause an ambiguous base error. Of course the real problem isn't like this, because `tuple<tuple<>>` doesn't produce any error.

The real implementation that caused the error is like this:

```
template<size_t _Idx, typename _Head>
struct _Head_base : public _Head
{};

template<size_t _Idx, typename... _Elements>
struct _Tuple_impl;

template<size_t _Idx>
struct _Tuple_impl<_Idx> {};

template<size_t _Idx, typename _Head, typename... _Tail>
struct _Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail...>
    : public _Tuple_impl<_Idx + 1, _Tail...>,
      private _Head_base<_Idx, _Head>
{
    typedef _Tuple_impl<_Idx + 1, _Tail...> _Inherited;
    constexpr _Tuple_impl() = default;
    constexpr _Tuple_impl(_Tuple_impl&& __in) : _Inherited(std::move(__in)) {}
};

template<typename... _Elements>
struct tuple : public _Tuple_impl<0, _Elements...> {};
```

When we instantiate `tuple<tuple<tuple<>>>`, we get this inheritance hierarchy:

[image: inheritance diagram of <code>tuple<tuple<tuple<>>></code> in libstdc++]

We see that `_Tuple_impl<1>` is reachable in two different paths. This is not yet the problem, the problem is in the move constructor, who invokes the move-conversion constructor of `_Tuple_impl<1>`. Which `_Tuple_impl<1>` do you want? The compiler doesn't know, so it chooses the give up.

(In your case it's because of `_Head_base<0, tuple<>>` as you are instantiating `tuple<tuple<>, tuple<tuple<>>>` instead, but the principle is the same.)

---

Why libc++ does not have the same problem? There are two main reasons:

1. `tuple<T...>` in libc++ use composition instead of inheritance to refer to `__tuple_impl<...>`.
2. As a result, the empty base class optimization in `__tuple_leaf<tuple<tuple<>>>` does not kick in, i.e. `__tuple_leaf<tuple<tuple<>>>` won't inherit from `tuple<tuple<>>`
3. Therefore, the ambiguous base class problem won't happen.
4. (and each base is unique as mentioned by @mitchnull, but that is not a main difference here.)

[image: inheritance diagram of <code>tuple<tuple<tuple<>>></code> in libc++]

As we can see above, if `tuple<...>` uses inheritance instead of composition, OP's `tuple<tuple<>, tuple<tuple<>>>` will still inherit from `__tuple_leaf<0, tuple<>>` twice, which might be a problem.

Comment: I see, does libc++ use a nonrecursive tuple implementation?

Comment: Actually, libc++ also uses multiple inheritence in the implementation, but it's "flat", and each base is unique. For the details, you can check my post about it at http://mitchnull.blogspot.com/2012/06/c11-tuple-implementation-details-part-1.html.

Comment: @mitchnull: Actually, I've checked libc++'s implementation in detail, the crucial point isn't the "flat" inheritance, but that `tuple<tuple<>>` is not an empty class. See update.

Comment: @KennyTM so in libc++ sizeof(tuple<char,tuple<tuple<>>>)>1 ?

Answer (score 0):

By the way, for those who have to use gcc, let me give you a quick and **dirty** fix (for 4.8.0, already submitted a bug report) :

The solution is a small modification of __empty_not_final in the tuple implementation, to prevent empty base optimisation for tuple<> type :

```
template<typename _Tp>
    using __empty_not_final
      = typename conditional<__is_final(_Tp)||is_same<_Tp,tuple<>>::value,
false_type, is_empty<_Tp>>::type;
```

instead of

```
template<typename _Tp>
    using __empty_not_final
      = typename conditional<__is_final(_Tp), false_type, is_empty<_Tp>>::type;
```

(Note that, this is only an adhoc solution for tuple<> type, it does not solve the real problem described by KennyTM, i.e. `struct A{}; auto d = std::tuple<std::tuple<std::tuple<A, A>, A>, A>{};` still does not compile)